# Remainder of Taylor series and CLT proof

Tags: probability-theory, taylor-expansion, self-learning, central-limit-theorem

I'm trying to understand part of the proof of the Central Limit Theorem in Casella Berger 2E. I realize there are many functionally equivalent ways to prove the CLT, but there's a specific step the authors use that I'm trying to find justification for.

To summarize the salient parts, suppose we have a random variable $Y$ with mean 0 and variance 1, and its MGF exists for |$t$| < some positive $h$. We're interested in the limiting behavior of $M_Y(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})$, where $M_Y(t)$ is the MGF of $Y$. The Maclaurin expansion follows as:

$M_Y(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}}) = 1 + \frac{(t/\sqrt{n})^2}{2} + R_Y(\frac{t}{\sqrt{n}})$

The authors then use $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{R_Y(t/\sqrt{n})}{(t/\sqrt{n})^2}=0$ in the proof, and they appear to justify that step by citing later "Taylor's major theorem, which we will not prove here, is that the remainder from the approximation $g(x)-T_r(x)$ always tends to 0 faster than the highest-order explicit term".

Which result or formulation of Taylor's Theorem justifies this limiting behavior?

Comment: You might find it helpful to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Motivation). The result you want is the one described in the 'quadratic approximation' bit (of course, the proper statement of the theorem can be found further down but that says essentially the same thing). Using the notation found there, your $\frac{R_y(t/\sqrt{n})}{(t / \sqrt{n})^2}$ is the same as $h_2(t/\sqrt{n})$ which goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.